# django-filter more results when explicitly setting a filter value

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to understand what happens what a field specified in the `filterset_fields` of the viewset is not specified.
My viewset is the following:

```
class DetectionTrainingViewSet(
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet
    ):
    queryset = Detection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DetectionSerializer
    filterset_fields = (
        'annotation_set__annotator__id',
        'annotation_set__bbox__annotator__id',
    )
```

I am making the following GET calls my endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/detections/:

- `?annotation_set__annotator__id=2` -> I get 4 results
- `?annotation_set__annotator__id=2&annotation_set__bbox__annotator__id=2` -> I get 16 results
  I expected the second call to return a subset of the following one. What's happening here? How can I specify that when a parameter is not explicitly specified any value (if it does not exist) should match the query?

Answer (score 0):

Adding here since this is too long for a comment:

This shouldn't happen, the fields should be `and`ed, and in my experience they are.  I can see no reason why this would not work from the code you've given.

1. How many total records are there
2. Can you see, on the server side, the exact request received?
3. How *exactly* are you sending this request? cli? browser?

The only thing I can think is that the querystring is getting mangled (possibly by urlencoding it) before sending.

Here is some simple `print()` debugging you can add to the viewset to check at various points and without attaching a debugger.

```
# add this to print the actual query text before & after filtering
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
     print("[before]", queryset.query)
     queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
     print("[after ]", queryset.query)
     return queryset

# add this override to see what your path / qs / etc are
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.path)
    print(request.META["QUERY_STRING"])
    print(request.query_params)
    return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have a similar case, I have added these prints but I am not getting any printout.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question.  These go in a Viewset, maybe you are using an APIView?